# Issue with DNS Naming and Certificates LDAP Context

Tags: java, ldap, certificate

With the last update of Java 1.8.0_181 I have an issue when I try to create a LDAPS connection to Active Directory. Up to version 1.8.0_171 using the following code I could create it without issues

```
Hashtable<String, Object> objEnvironment;
    objEnvironment = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
    objEnvironment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    objEnvironment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "LDAPS://domain:636");
    objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, <username>);
    objEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, <Password>);
    objEnvironment.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", <attributes>);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "certificates".concat(File.separator).concat("cacerts"));
    this.objLDAPContext = new InitialLdapContext(objEnvironment, null);
```

However with the last version I get the following exception java.security.cert.CertificateException: No DNS name found for xxxx.xxxx.xxx
Looking it up I found it is an issue with the FDQN name, if I do not use the same name as it is displayed on the certificate, I can not establish a connection. I would like to know if there is a way to skip this and can use the domain name as I did in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing may be due to the changes introduced in `Java 1.8.0_181` for improved LDAP Support. Refer the release notes [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u181-relnotes-4479407.html).

> ➜ Improve LDAP support Endpoint identification has been enabled on
>   LDAPS connections.
>
> To improve the robustness of LDAPS (secure LDAP over TLS )
>   connections, endpoint identification algorithms have been enabled by
>   default.
>
> Note that there may be situations where some applications that were
>   previously able to successfully connect to an LDAPS server may no
>   longer be able to do so. Such applications may, if they deem
>   appropriate, disable endpoint identification using a new system
>   property: com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification.
>
> Define this system property (or set it to true) to disable endpoint
>   identification algorithms.

You may use the workaround to add `-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true` while running your code.

Note that this is not a recommended approach, as your system will continue to be vulnerable using this approach.

Comment: Probably you correctly identified the problem but your proposed "solution" is to disable a security mechanism. Way too often I saw copy&pasta crap like this going to production. No wonder why hackers have an easy life breaking into systems. => down-vote

Comment: Yes , this is not a recommended approach. This is just a workaround where immediately making a change is difficult and a temporary solution is required to keep things going.

Comment: But what you simply call "keep things going" means it will go into production. Where do you draw the line beyond which **not** to use your "solution"?